# Setting Label object as per Listbox selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I need to bind a `Label` to two `ListBox`es. In order to do this I have set the `SelectionChanged` property of both `ListBox`es to the same function:

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox1" SelectionChanged="UpdateSelectedItem" />
<ListBox Name="ListBox2" SelectionChanged="UpdateSelectedItem" />
<Label Name="DetailsLabel" DataContent="DefinedElsewhere" />
```

However I am having trouble finding what the selected item actually is. I have gone through all the properties of the sending object and the SelectionChangedEventArgs but I cannot find it. The `ListBox` is bound to an `ObservableCollection` of objects, and I would like the `Label` to display the properties of the last selected item, no matter from which `ListBox` it was selected. How do I find that?

```
private void UpdateSelectedItem(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     DetailsLabel.Content = ???;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the selected item text doing something like:

```
ListBoxItem item = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
String itemText = (item != null) ? item.Content.ToString() : String.Empty;
```

You have to cast the SelectedItem property to the type of object you have in the list.
In this example I've used ListBoxItem.